GDB debugger can't show correct value of Qt‘s container in Qt Creator
Here is my code:
    QList<int> a;
    a.push_back(10);
    a.push_back(11);
    int b = 11;
    QVector<int> c = {13, 14};
    qreal d = 10.0;

When I debug with gdb in Qt Creator, it can't show the value of a and c. But it can show the value of b and d.
Here is the result:

The OS version is Deepin 23. My Qt version is 5.14.2, and the gdb version is 13.2. How should I solve this problem?
Additional explanation: I tried debugging the QT program with CLion, but the result was the same. My CLion version is 2024.1.4  and the gdb version in Clion is 14.1.

Have you looked at "Using Debugging Helpers"?

Yes, I checked the option and unchecked the option, the result was the same without any changes. @G.M.
